# Ionic2 console.log wont work on root page constructer

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Basically, I'm trying to print something when my application is loaded. alert working fine but I can not see console logs on Xcode or safari development console. Why is this happening?

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController....){
    alert("login constructer!!!"); // its working fine
    console.log("CONFIGURE FROM LOGIN.TS !!"); // i can't see this in console.
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
     console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage'); // i can't see this one
  }
```

Comment: What commands are you using to start the application?

Comment: `ionic cordova build ios` then build on Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Try running the application with the following command line [options](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/serve/) to enable `console.log()` output in either the dev tools or chrome://inspect/#devices:

```
ionic serve -l -c -s
```

Or:

```
ionic cordova run ios -l -c -s --debug
```

For the [build](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/) you could try:

```
ionic cordova build ios --debug
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I'm using many cordova plugin that need real device. I cant use `run ios' because of CORS things...

Comment: Try `ionic cordova build ios --debug`